# Is it necessary to transfer `tar` files through `rsync` in archive mode?

Tags: rsync, backup, tar

I have a bunch of `tar` files in my machine which I want to transfer to an external hard drive (EHD); they where created preserving permissions (using the `-p` flag). I plan to use `rsync` to copy them to the EHD, but I wonder if it's necessary to transfer them in the so called "archive mode" (using the `-a` flag), since, as I understand, the main purpose of this mode is to preserve permissions, ownerships, etc.

Answer (score 1):

It's the right way to use  `-a` . One of the benefits of using `RSYNC` is that it will only copy changes the next time you want to sync destination with source changes.

I use it like this:

```
rsync -avz ~/home/user/blah USER@HOST:/home/user/blahblah
```

Form Rsync man page:

**- -a, --archive
       This is equivalent to -rlptgoD. It is a quick way of saying you want recursion and want to preserve almost everything (with -H being
   a notable omission). The only exception to the above equivalence is
   when --files-from is specified, in which case -r is not implied.
       Note that -a does not preserve hardlinks, because
       finding multiply-linked files is expensive. You must separately specify -H.**

Check this Server Fault post out: [What is archive mode in rsync?](https://serverfault.com/questions/141773/what-is-archive-mode-in-rsync)

Comment: Misses the point of the question: will it matter for a `tar` archive, since all the permissions are contained inside?

Answer (score 0):

No. Since you already created a tar file, `rsync` would only look at the permissions of that file. Those are irrelevant, obviously.

You don't even need to use `rsync`; the file is on a local hard drive, after all. You can just use `cp` instead.